# Chart.js change vertical position of points

Tags: javascript, chart.js

I extend `Chart.types.Line` and override scale to some constant value.

What I need now - to show points with

- `y > scale.max` at `scale.max` position
- `y < scale.min` at `scale.min` position

to ability of user interaction with them.
Titles should be correct(not modified) values, so I can't just modify datasets.

How can I achieve that?

Simplified code:

```
function ChartFactory(title) {
  Chart.types.Line.extend({
    name: title,
    buildScale: function() {
        this.options.scaleOverride = true;
        this.options.scaleSteps = 10;
        this.options.scaleStepWidth = this.options.S;
        this.options.scaleStartValue = this.options.target - 5 * this.options.S;
        Chart.types.Line.prototype.buildScale.apply(this, arguments);      
    },
    draw: function () {
        var chart = this;
        Chart.types.Line.prototype.draw.apply(chart, arguments);
        // some additional graphic here 
    }
  });
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just add the following at the end of your `buildScale`

```
...
var scale = this.scale;
var originalCalculateY = scale.calculateY;
scale.calculateY = function(y) {
    if (y > scale.max)
        return originalCalculateY.apply(this, [scale.max]);
    else if (y < scale.min)
        return originalCalculateY.apply(this, [scale.min]);
    else
        return originalCalculateY.apply(this, [y]);
}
...
```

It would a bit confusing because you'd still have the axis labels.

---

Fiddle - http://jsfiddle.net/wjb3k4gx/

Comment: Awesome, just what I looking for.